# How to pass the information from servlet to normal java class or java bean

Tags: java, servlets

How to get the information which is stored in a session of servlet from a normal java class..

Comment: Calling public methods of java class.

Comment: What is meant by normal here ? Is this class not the part of same webapp as the servlet ?

Comment: it is in the same webapp

Comment: I think Normal java class means The class which do not extends Httpservlet class or not Implemented any servlet interface. I am having same problem @saury ,

Answer (score 2):

As with any other class: by passing it as an argument of a constructor or method:

```
MyJavaClass c1 = new MyJavaClass(session.getAttribute("foo"));
MyOtherJavaClass c2 = new MyOtherJavaClass();
c2.doSomethingWithSession(session);
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally I would make information flow *from* the servlet to the class: the servlet initiates the actions it requires, passing along any information that's needed to perform those actions.

I would try to isolate the other classes from any knowledge of servlets and sessions as far as possible - the servlet should know about its collaborators, rather than the other way round.

(If this doesn't help for your specific situation, please tell us more about what you're trying to do.)

Comment: actually i have a value which is stored in a session while log in to the app. i want to get that session value in a java class of same application

Comment: @pmad: Sorry, it's not really clear what you mean to be honest.

Comment: :Actually my application needs to connect to different databases based on one parameter i.e account name. I have this parameter in session. But how can i get this parameter in normal java classes.

Comment: @pmad: As I've said: you pass it down from the servlet. Presumably you're performing some action in response to a request, right? So your servlet code is calling into your non-servlet code - so pass the values down at that point.

Answer (score 0):

HttpSession objHttpSession=request.getSession().getAttribute(@argument@);